# Cannot change style of Office UI React Dialog ver. 5.56.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, office-ui-fabric

I'm using old version of office-ui-fabric-react (5.56.0). So my Dialog component has only getStyles property. The problem is that it seems like dialog width is blocked and i can't figure out how to change it. I tried to change its content but this doesn't make the dialog itself wider.

I also tried this solution: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/issues/5175
But it didnt workout. I tried to change the function to this:

```
getStyles(): IDialogStyles {
        return {
            root: [{
                displayName: '@media (min-width: 480px)',
                selectors: 
                    {
                        maxWidth: '900px',
                        minWidth: '800px'
                }
            }]
        };
    }
```

Still doesn't work. Mb anyone faced the same trouble?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like at this specific version of Fabric the Dialog was still using Sass for styling (even though the interface had been updated with getStyles).

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/blob/office-ui-fabric-react_v5.56.0/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/components/Dialog/Dialog.base.tsx#L11

So you can either style using CSS selectors, or try to upgrade to a newer version of Fabric.